# Do something for each loaded div in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, each

I'm trying to make a progressbar, and it loads a bit for each loaded div... Like this:

```
var length= $('div').length;
var widthOfTheBar = 81;

$('div').each(function(){
    $(this).load(function(){
        $('.loaded').animate({"width":"+="+(widthOfTheBar/length)+"px"},50);
    });
});
```

But it does not work... Help.

Comment: `div`s do not have load events, because there is nothing to load.

Comment: Please, which are the tags that load?

Comment: Tags that use external resources, like `<img>`, `<script>` - these have a load event. And the whole document. What do you mean when you say "loaded div"?

Comment: when evertyhing inside this div is completely loaded.

Comment: @JeanMichell You can't. There is no `load event` on a `DIV`.

Comment: Please, how do I get the length of all of the tags that use external resources and save in a var?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here - as some friends said above - is to use tags with external resources. Like `<img src="">` and `<script src="">` Because DIVs have no `load` events.